# Matrix Factorisation Improvement

Tags: python, recommender-system, matrix-factorisation

I am using SGD matrix factorisation (python) using the movielens dataset to make recommendations. I have a website which allows users to give feedback which is positive or negative to whether an item is a good recommendation for a particular movie.

I was wondering if I could use this feedback in my matrix factorisation. I wasn't 100% sure how I would proceed.

So for example I would have a vector like

```
  m1 m2 m3
m1 0 0  0
m2 5 0 -4
m3 0 0  0
```

Where m2-m1 is a score of 5 so with an example case where noone rated it negative, 5 people think its good. With the other for m2-m3 being -4 so a poor recommendation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: response from answer

I am currently using a sparse matrix for user item ratings and am using bias.

I have been trying to add additional input sources and am using the following to create a attribute matrix containing a genre representation:

```
for genre in item_genres:
       genres[genre] = 1
       self.attribute_item_matrix[i] = sum(list(genres.values()))


 pred = self.global_mean + self.bias_user[u] + self.bias_item[i] +np.dot(self.P[u, :],(self.Q[:, i]+self.attribute_item_matrix[i]))
```

However, I don't think this is correct as it eventually fails and causes a nan error.

I have been following this paper [Matrix Factorisation Techniques for recommender systems](https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/Recommender-Systems-[Netflix].pdf)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my view, you should better go for `user`-`movie` matrix, to create a `sparse matrix` that can be more meaningful. By doing that, if you already know `polarity` of choices i.e. `positive`, `negative` or `neutral`, you may also have some `intensity` score of `like` or `dislike` like in case of `rating`. Now, if you want to just classify them as `likes`, `neutral`, and `dislike`, you may assign `1`,`0` and `-1` respectively. This method can have more meaning when you have many movies and many users. Further this can help you establish `user-user`, `movie-user` and `movie-movie` relationship as well. These relationship can potentially help you understand and explore more about `recommendation engines`.

```
     m1 m2 m3 m4
u1 -1   0  -1  1
u2  1   1  -1  0
u3  0   0   1  0
u4  -1  1   1   0
```

If you want to add `rating` instead of just `polarity`, just add numbers scaled `0-1`. I personally worked on them to write `hybrid recommendation engines` which have both `collaborative filtering` and `context based filtering` models embedded. I would suggest you to work more on relationships and try to explore more about next steps like possibility of `like` or `dislike` bias, association of movie info/ actors-directors influence and similarity in movies etc. I hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are some factorization models that kind of work like that, you can do a search for 'session-based', 'basket-based', 'sequential' and others. But they tend not to perform very well. You can also use that data to create a classification or regression model and then mix it up with regular user-item-rating triplets in some hybrid model.